# How to compare von Neumann entropy of a general composite state

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

Suppose that we have two systems $A$  and $B$ in states $|{\psi}\rangle_A$ and $| \phi\rangle_B$ respectively. The state of the composite system is given by their tensor product,written in short as
$|{\psi}\rangle_A |{\phi}\rangle_B$. Can we ,in general comment on when the von neumann entropy of such a composite state will be highest ? Can we write the entropy in this case, and deduce when it will be maximum/minimum?

Comment: The states are pure. The entropy is thus 0.

Answer (score 2):

The von Neumann entropy is always zero for pure states. Did you mean for the tensor product of two mixed state? Then the von Neumann entropy is just the sum of the von Neumann entropy of the two subsystems, i.e.
$$S(\rho_A\otimes\rho_B)=S(\rho_A)+S(\rho_B)$$
and this is maximized if both states are the maximally mixed states. In this case we have that $$S((\mathbb{I}_{A}/d_A)\otimes(\mathbb{I}_{B}/d_B))=\log(d_A)+\log(d_B).$$
Or did you mean for an arbitrary two-partite state, then this is maximized by the same state, i.e.
$$\mathbb{I}_{AB}/(d_Ad_B)=(\mathbb{I}_A/d_A)\otimes(\mathbb{I}_B/d_B).$$